# Show all solutions of an ODE tend toward a single limit as $t$ approaches infinity and find the limiting value

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE $2y'+ty=2$

Show that all solutions approach a limit as $t\to \infty$.

I've found 
\begin{align}
y=\exp(-t^2/4)\int_0^t \exp(s^2/4) \mathrm{d}s + Ce^{-t^2/4}
\end{align}
However, I am unsure how to show that all solutions will approach a single limit as $t\to \infty$.

*I should add that my thought is: Split this into two limits so that $\lim  y = \lim y_1 + \lim y_2$, where $y_1 = C\exp(-t^2/4)$ and $y_2 =\int_0^t \exp(-s^2/4) \mathrm{d}s/ \exp(t^2/4)$.

$y_1$ is straightforward and I think using L.H. rule on the second would be useful. But does this work for all solutions and, more importantly, does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work, because $\lim_{t\to\infty} y_{1} + y_{2} = \lim_{t\to \infty} y_{1} + \lim_{t\to\infty} y_{2}$ whenever both limits $\lim_{t\to \infty} y_{1}$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty} y_{2}$ exist.

In addition, L'Hopital's rule is a good choice here, because
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{t} \exp(s^2/4) \, \mathrm{d}s}{\exp(t^2/4)} 
&= \lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_{0}^{t} \exp(s^2/4) \, \mathrm{d}s}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\exp(t^2/4)} \\
&= \lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{\exp(t^2/4)}{t\exp(t^2/4)/2} \\
&= \lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{2}{t} = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: @ nick - Could you add a bit of detail between those steps. I'm very rusty with my Cal. 2 - how do you deal with the numerator here?

Comment: Does that help or do you need more?

Comment: I *assumed* I could use L.H. because the integral in the numerator doesn't exist (in a conventional sense...that statement may violate some deeper understanding of what is happening here). The part that gave me trouble was being able to say with certainty why exactly the original form is indeterminate. I do not want to tell my professor I simply made an assumption - I think I need to actually understand.